# Checking file extension in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am trying to check the file extension but for some reason `Valid` is always false.

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="LogoUpload" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" /><asp:Button ID="BtnLogoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload" />
                 <asp:Label ID="lblLUploadMessage" runat="server"  ForeColor="Red" ></asp:Label>

Protected Sub BtnLogoUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogoUpload.Click
        If (LogoUpload.HasFile) Then
            Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(LogoUpload.FileName)
            Dim extension = New String() {"jpg", "png", "gif"}
            Dim Valid As Boolean = False
            For Each ext As String In extension
                If ext.Equals(fileExtension) Then
                    Valid = True
                End If
            Next
            If Valid = True Then
                LogoUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", "~/CW/uploads", register_username.Text, "logo") + LogoUpload.FileName)) ' Save file in directory
                lblLUploadMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully"
                lblLUploadMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            Else
                lblLUploadMessage.Text = "File extension is not valid"

            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am always getting `File extension is not valid`

Comment: Have you tried `IO` namespace? Or `my.computer.filesystem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `Path.GetExtension` has a catch. As described in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx), the return value of this method is:

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or
>   null, or String.Empty.

The important part here is ***(including the period ".")***. This means that if you upload the bmp file, method `Path.GetExtension` returns not `bmp`, but `.bmp`.

So in order to make it work you have to use extensions with periods:

```
Dim extension = New String() {".jpg", ".png", ".gif"}
```

or trim period from the start of extension before making your checks:

```
Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(LogoUpload.FileName)
fileExtension = fileExtension.TrimStart("."c)
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks for the help